# how to remove index.php and folder name from url in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting

URL: localhost/studentlibrary2/index.php/front_side/home

remove from URL index.php/front_side

how to remove "index.php/front_side"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

Comment: No.i want to also remove subfolder from url.ex index.php/folder/controller/method.  i want to remove folder frome URL

Comment: See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116031/codeigniter-remove-directory-from-url) if it can help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```